# Include vb.net modules in compilation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have created a program in vb.net using Visual Studio Express 2013, and I compile it there, it works fine except the modules. It doesn't include mysql.data (which is essential to the application). How do I include these modules in the compilation? (I already tried putting the .dll in the solution explorer.)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is to include the file in the project by: `Right-Click on solution > Add file`.

Once done, set “**Build Action**” to “***Content***” and its “**Copy to Output Directory**” mode to “***Copy if newer***” from the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Add Reference and Add .DLL file reference using browse option.